# Automatic resizing header seems to rely on a PHP Echo. I don't want the echo to display anything though.

Tags: javascript, php

I have some code that works out your screen resolution and then resizing a header based on the results.

If it's 1600x900 we don't want to resize, we want to keep the header as 1500x500. 
Otherwise, we set the header to 100% each.

However. 
At 1600x900 the header will resize, code doesn't work, UNLESS I echo a previous piece of code that displays the users screen resolution on screen. I don't actually want to display that echo though.

If I go in and echo, then delete the echo, it'll work, but I need it to work first time. So i'm wondering if there's some way to echo without actually printing or an equivalent idea.

Relevant header code:

```
<!-- This is start of header code -->
<!-- All you need to do is put in the new header image and change site title like before -->
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['screen_width']) AND isset($_SESSION['screen_height']))
    {
        <!-- put a echo here for debugging -->
        'User resolution: ' . $_SESSION['screen_width'] . 'x' . $_SESSION['screen_height'];
    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['width']) AND isset($_REQUEST['height'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['screen_width'] = $_REQUEST['width'];
        $_SESSION['screen_height'] = $_REQUEST['height'];
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    } 
    else
    {
       <!-- put a echo here for debugging -->
       '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>';
    }
?>

<!-- Note, putting those echos above will fix my site so that on 1600x900 it won't be 100% anymore. THEN removing echo will have the site the way I want it but this isn't ideal. I need it to work first time since other non-programmers will be working with this code -->

<?php if ($_SESSION['screen_width'] == 1600 && $_SESSION['screen_height'] == 900)
{
     //Don't change style, this is a resolution we want precise width on
    $width1 = "1500"."px";
    $height1 = "500"."px";
    //echo $width1;
    //echo $height1;
    //echo "Header won't change";
}
else
{
      //Change style, any other resolution we go for 100%
    $width1 = "100"."%";
    $height1 = "100"."%";
    //echo $width1;
    //echo $height1;
    //echo "Header will change";
}

$text = "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/AdK7a7u.png' style='width:$width1;height:$height1></center>";

preg_match_all("/<img.*>/",$text,$out);
foreach($out as $t1)
{
    foreach($t1 as $img)
    {
        preg_match("/.*height:(.*?);width:(.*?);.*/",$img,$out2);
        $height = $out2[1];
        $width = $out2[2];
        $text = str_replace($out2[0],str_replace("<img","<img width='" . $width1 . "' height='" . $height1 . "'",$out2[0]),$text);
    }
}
echo $text;
?>
```

Images of the code running on a site:

[Expected output for 1600x900](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVvKw.png)

[Actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y9eJ.png)

[What the echo looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrCbK.png)

Comment: never heard of CSS media queries? Make it responsive! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I...I don't know how that's supposed to help me, sorry. 

I'm working with what i've got, I don't know where I would begin with that @media stuff. I would rather we discuss the code I presented as it feels like it's literally 1 step away from being as intended rather than rewriting the whole thing. 

Thanks.

Comment: your code is a hack. it's waaay easier to set your image width and height with som simple css rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSS with media queries to achieve this. As an example, I add CSS class "img" to my image tag:

```
<img class="img" src="http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/trollface/success-troll-smiley-emoticon.png">
```

Then, in CSS, you can define different rules for different screen widths etc:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .img{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
  .img{
    width:100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  .img{
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Obviously, put in the actual CSS rules you need, mine are just examples. Then if you drag your browser window to a different size, you will see each CSS rule kick in automatically as each rule takes precendence.

Read up on media queries here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand what you meant originally. Your first example helped a lot actually in making you understand how to go about this, I didn't even realise the img class was a CSS thing.

I was trying to do everything in the header. This solution was sooo much easier, you're right. 

I added height / width 100% in the img class in the header, as that's what I want most of the time. And then in style.css, found in a themes folder, I added a width:1600px rule so my specific resolution I don't want to be 100% I can modify the height/width as I desire.

Thanks a ton dude. :)

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer please? BTW, the class name `img` is just a name i gave it, you could call it anything! `.header-image` or whatever!